# DragSortListView Library and DropListener in ListFragment Class

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-listfragment

I am currently trying to implement the DSLV library into my ListFragment class and I am getting the error

```
04-28 17:43:13.876: E/AndroidRuntime(17113): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-28 17:43:13.876: E/AndroidRuntime(17113): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:         com.main.tab.FavoritesTab$1
04-28 17:43:13.876: E/AndroidRuntime(17113):    at com.main.tab.FavoritesTab.<init>(FavoritesTab.java:43)
04-28 17:43:13.876: E/AndroidRuntime(17113):    at com.main.transit.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:85)
04-28 17:43:13.876: E/AndroidRuntime(17113):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
04-28 17:43:13.876: E/AndroidRuntime(17113):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
04-28 17:43:13.876: E/AndroidRuntime(17113):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
04-28 17:43:13.876: E/AndroidRuntime(17113):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2357)
04-28 17:43:13.876: E/AndroidRuntime(17113):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:153)
04-28 17:43:13.876: E/AndroidRuntime(17113):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
04-28 17:43:13.876: E/AndroidRuntime(17113):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-28 17:43:13.876: E/AndroidRuntime(17113):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-28 17:43:13.876: E/AndroidRuntime(17113):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5226)
04-28 17:43:13.876: E/AndroidRuntime(17113):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-28 17:43:13.876: E/AndroidRuntime(17113):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-28 17:43:13.876: E/AndroidRuntime(17113):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
04-28 17:43:13.876: E/AndroidRuntime(17113):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
04-28 17:43:13.876: E/AndroidRuntime(17113):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

According to the error, it would appear that line 43 is causing a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:. It seems that declarations of the DropListener is causing the issue. Could it also be caused by a declaration I've made in the xml file? Here is the source code:

```
public class FavoritesTab extends ListFragment
{
private JazzAdapter adapter;

private ArrayList<JazzArtist> mArtists;

private String[] mArtistNames = {"Brighouse Stn Bay 7", "Nb No.3 Rd Fs Francis Rd", "Sb Westbrook Mall Fs University--"};
private String[] mArtistAlbums = {"402: 1:40pm, 2:10pm\n403: 1:39pm, 2:01pm, 2:22pm\n404: 1:46pm, 2:16pm\n410: 1:39pm, 1:50pm, 2:09pm, 2:19pm, 2:23pm\n",
        "403: 1:53pm, 2:13pm, 2:33pm\n",
        "025: 1:38pm, 1:50pm, 2:02pm, 2:14pm, 2:26pm\n033: 2:01pm, 2:31pm\n041: 1:45pm, 2:08pm, 2:25pm\n"};
private String[] mStops = {"56549", "56616", "61598"};

private DragSortListView.DropListener onDrop =
    new DragSortListView.DropListener() {
        @Override
        public void drop(int from, int to) {
            JazzArtist item = adapter.getItem(from);

            adapter.remove(item);
            adapter.insert(item, to);
        }
    };

private DragSortListView.RemoveListener onRemove = 
    new DragSortListView.RemoveListener() {
        @Override
        public void remove(int which) {
            adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(which));
        }
    };

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
 @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        MainActivity ma = (MainActivity) getActivity();

        DragSortListView lv = (DragSortListView) getListView(); 

        lv.setDropListener(onDrop);
        lv.setRemoveListener(onRemove);

        mArtists = new ArrayList<JazzArtist>();

        for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
            JazzArtist ja = new JazzArtist();
            ja.name = mArtistNames[i];
            ja.albums = mArtistAlbums[i];
            ja.stop_no = mStops[i];
            mArtists.add(ja);
        }

        adapter = new JazzAdapter(mArtists);

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        //ma.refreshList();
    }

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_favorites_tab, container, false);
    return view;
}

private class JazzArtist {
      public String name;
      public String albums;
      public String stop_no;

      @Override
      public String toString() {
        return name;
      }
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
      public TextView albumsView;
      public TextView stopNo;
    }

    private class JazzAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<JazzArtist> {

      public JazzAdapter(List<JazzArtist> artists) {
        super(getActivity(), R.layout.jazz_artist_list_item,
          R.id.artist_name_textview, artists);
      }

      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        if (v != convertView && v != null) {
          ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

          TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.artist_albums_textview);
          TextView tv2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.stop_number_textview);
          holder.albumsView = tv;
          holder.stopNo = tv2;

          v.setTag(holder);
        }

        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        String albums = getItem(position).albums;
        String stop_no = "Bus Stop " + getItem(position).stop_no;

        holder.albumsView.setText(albums);
        holder.stopNo.setText(stop_no);

        return v;
      }
    }
```

}

edit - As it turns out, I didn't import the library properly. However, I am now presented with a new issue. I am getting the error

```
04-28 21:19:34.786: E/AndroidRuntime(32514): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-28 21:19:34.786: E/AndroidRuntime(32514): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class com.mobeta.android.dslv.DragSortListView
```

Here is my XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.mobeta.android.dslv.DragSortListView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:dslv="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingTop="7dp"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:dividerHeight="5dp"
    dslv:drag_enabled="true"
    dslv:collapsed_height="2dp"
    dslv:drag_scroll_start="0.33"
    dslv:max_drag_scroll_speed="0.5"
    dslv:float_alpha="0.6"
    dslv:slide_shuffle_speed="0.3"
    dslv:track_drag_sort="false"
    dslv:use_default_controller="true"
    dslv:sort_enabled="false"
    dslv:remove_enabled="true"
    dslv:remove_mode="flingRemove"
    android:background="#E5E5E5" />
```

If I change the line "xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"" to  "    xmlns:dslv="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.mobeta.android.demodslv"
", I will get a "No resource ifentifier found" error.

Comment: Do you have the required jars in libs/ ?

Comment: I believe so, as the demo from which this is derived from did not have any .jar files int he lib folder. android v4 support is already included in the library.

Answer (score 1):

You might have the wrong url. It should be :  http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.mobeta.android.dslv
You are hitting the demo project with "com.mobeta.android.demodslv"

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your DragSortListView is not added as a library in the project. It is not always necessary to include a jar in project libs. Sometimes a whole project can be used as library.
Check in the demos if it includes the DSLV project by checking the properties-->Android under library.

Comment: Thanks, I think the issue before was that I didn't properly import the library properly. However, now I am getting a different issue. I am getting the error "android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class com.mobeta.android.dslv.DragSortListView". The xml code for this layout is edited into the first post.

Comment: you'll actually have to point towards your package name in xmlns:dslv. the xmlns attribute actually works as namespace and should point towards the source of attributes.

Comment: If I point my xmlns using the line     "xmlns:dslv="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.mobeta.android.demodslv"", I will get a no resource identifier found error.

Comment: have you tried putting your applications package name after res/..?

Comment: My appoligies. The site shortened the url. I meant

xmlns:dslv="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res /com.mobeta.android.demodslv"

Comment: how did you imported the library then?because this error indicates that the eclipse is still having problem to detect class. Have you added it to buildpath?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of android do you use? ListFragment can be used in version 11. You have to add the 'support.v4.jar'.

Comment: My target api is 16 w/ minimum at 11. The DSLV library already has support v4 included.